# Why is this IF executing?

Tags: php, debugging, if-statement

There's a block of code that supposed to be a fail-safe termination point. I want to know exactly why is it that it's executing. i.e. Why is this following `IF` executing? Which among its bundled conditions make it overall `true`?

```
if ( !$result && !(-1 == $action && strpos($referer, $adminurl) === 0) ) {
    wp_nonce_ays($action);
    die();
    }
```

[image]

Comment: How would we know without the code that is before this condition ? If the whole condition is true, then both conditions are true... why aren't you debugging by displaying the values, you'll see which one si the cause...

Comment: Well `result` is `false` and `action` looks like it's `"$pluginmaker_nonce"`, so both operands of `&&` are true...

Comment: Above the code is the description. > Makes sure that a user was referred from another admin page. To avoid
> security exploits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ( !$result && !(-1 == $action && strpos($referer, $adminurl) === 0) ) {
```

That means `!$result` is true, and `!(-1 == $action && strpos($referer, $adminurl) === 0)` is true. (when `a && b` is true, then `a` is true and `b` is true.)

Therefore, `$result` is false, and `-1 == $action && strpos($referer, $adminurl) === 0` is false. (removing the `!` signs)

Then you can go on to say that

1. `$result` is false
2. Either `-1 != $action` or `strpos($referer, $adminurl) !== 0`. (or both)